# Reading percentage encoded url with umlauts with Qt

Tags: qt, qstring, urldecode, qurl

I am trying to read percentage encoded urls with umlauts, such as äüö,..., with Qt:

```
QString str = "Nu%CC%88rnberg"
qDebug() << QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(str.toUtf8());
```

But the output is `Nu¨rnberg` instead of `Nürnberg`. How can I correctly decode urls with umlauts in this form?

Regards,

Comment: Your code looks correct. Where do you see the incorrect string? If you output it to a terminal window, it might be that it fails to show unicode characters.

Comment: The output to the terminal window was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this issue but I am little confused with result. First if you want to use letter `ü` use `%C3%BC` not `%CC%88` (according to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). So you need

```
QString str = "N%C3%BCrnberg";
QString encoded = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(str.toUtf8());
```

But if you output it in `qDebug()` stream you can get different symbol (I guess it is because your default system encoding). But if you output it in GUI element you will have your `ü` symbol

```
QMessageBox::information(this, "", encoded);
```

`this` means main window.